# How to place a set of div's inside a container center of webpage dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I want to have set of div's placed on the center of the page and its size should vary as per length of the username.

```
.Container1
{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Container2{
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-left:auto;
   width:100%;
   max-height:30px;
   padding:0; 
   overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="maincontainer" runat="server" class="Container1">
            <div class="Container2" runat="server">
                <div class="leftbar"><img src="Some image" runat="server" /></div>
                <div id="child1container" runat="server">
                    <span class="textclass" runat="server">UserName</span>
                    <span class="textclass" id="BankName" runat="server">BankName</span>
                    <span class = "Col"> ---Some Content --- </span>
                    <span class="barBtn"> ----Logout Button----
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="rightbar"><img src="Some image" runat="server"/></div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

The set of section inside Container2 are the one's that should be centralized. It occupies the top part of the webpage and should be positioned at the center and the container width should vary based on length of user name (eg: for longer names, the entire container should adjust and should be positioned at the center).

I would like to have this entire container behave as specified in the Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2t017sx/

If you vary the length of user name,it will expand from the center maintaining the entire container position center all the time. If I try to implement similar changes in my application as that of jfiddle,it is not picking the change. I want all  elements to be aligned in same line. I would like to know what property need to be set to container2 and child1container to have them behave in this manner. Can it be done using CSS or we can use javascript to alter the container size (CSS Style) based on the input values?

Answer (score 1):

add `text-align: center;` to `.Container2` which is the container:

```
.Container2 {
  border: 1px solid black; // enable this is for test container border
  display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/tc7kkzyz/2/